# XMLHttpRequest onunload?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

In my web app, I need to send the latest data the user has changed before they leave the page.

I call up a function like this when the page unloads:

```
window.onbeforeunload=sendData;
```

That's what's inside the function called

```
function sendData(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        var storage = container;
        xhr.open("POST","save.php",false);
        xhr.send("information="+container);
}
```

My questions:

1. What is more right: Using async or sync to make send the requests before the user closes the page?
2. Is it possible to make the requests smaller? I only send variables containing up to two characters and the whole request takes 171 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to use a synchronous request, otherwise, the data is not transmitted in IE10 and IE11, see [Unload event in IE10, no form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383939/unload-event-in-ie10-no-form-data).