# Unload event in IE10, no form data

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have window.unload hooked to save my form data in emergencies when the user just closes their browser. I send this using ajax via POST. This works in IE9, Chrome etc, but not in IE10 where the form data is empty (using GET is a workaround).

I can't find any references to this behaviour, is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you are using code like this:

```
<html>
   ...
   <body onunload="inOnUnload();">
      ...
```

with an `inOnUnload()`-function being defined like the following:

```
function inOnUnload() {
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://some-location", /*async*/ true);
   http.send(request);
}
```

The problem with this in IE10 is that it seems to cancel the request, after the document has finally been unloaded. This happens before the form data had a chance to leaf the client. To send data in `onunload` events in IE10, you must use the `async = false` parameter in `XMLHttpRequest.open(...)`.

The following works fine for me:

```
function inOnUnload() {
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://some-location", /*async*/ /*!!!*/ false);
   http.send(request);
}
```